# Maximum levels of validation in workflow (SharePoint Designer)

Tags: sharepoint-designer

When designing a workflow using SharePoint Designer, is there any maximum number of validation steps? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean workflow conditions? Or checking users permission levels?

Comment: I mean, the maximum number of "approvers" I can chain in a workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of validation steps is variable depending on what you are doing, but there is what's called a max complexity value that can be adjusted through powershell.

see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2557533